# Configuring Sending Encrypted Assertions to Relying Party Doesn't Work in Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, saml-2.0

I have configured my app according to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/connect-with-saml-service-providers

I see the assertion being made in the app insights logs but I always receive an exception. I was able to use the SP test application to test the config but once I configured encrypted assertions the B2C setup no longer functions.

Has anyone been able to get encrypted assertions working? The meta my SP app looks like this: https://clients.home.foe.hn/meta/captivateprimeeu_sp.xml

It has the right KeyDescriptor node as listed in the docs along with the public key my SP provided.

I receive the following errors in app insights:

the logs in app insights are as follows:

```js
{"Kind":"Action","Content":"Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.SendRelyingPartyResponseHandler"}
{"Kind":"FatalException","Content":{"Time":"9:57 PM","Exception":{"Kind":"Handled","HResult":"80131509","Message":"Sequence contains no elements","Data":{}​}}​}
```

Comment: The meta xml file you are provided is not found. Can you please attach the details correctly

Comment: The URL is active again.

Comment: @pixeldrew I am facing the same issue. Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I was able to yes, by reformatting the meta data. It's important that you have the right structure and you keep the namespaces correct.